# Not able to logout from my site using facebook login.?

Tags: php, mysql

When i login to my website using facebook login it is doing fine. But when i logout fro it and re login from a different account then it shows the name of the same person who has already logged out. So tell me any solution. I am using Core PHP.

Comment: use JS SDK for logout function.

Comment: @hisham, you can use `getLogoutUrl()`. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

there is some problem with new `facebook-sdk` in `logout link`..

use `session_destroy()` instead....

your logout URL like this `$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();`

but replace it with `$logoutUrl = 'logout.php';`

and in `logout.php` file put this code..

`session_start();
session_destroy();
header('location:your_login_page.php');`

if this doesnt work please try below two possible solutions

http://safeeronline.wordpress.com/2013/03/16/facebook-php-sdk-logout-issue-solved/..

http://samoldak.com/fixing-facebooks-php-sdk-logout/

let me know if you want any further guidance...

Comment: please elaborate your answer??!!

Comment: @NishantSolanki I have already stated this `$facebook->getLogoutUrl()` in my answer

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL I am providing my code.. I havent used your code.. and yeah both the answers are different.. I already have faced this issue before..

Comment: @hisham if you find the answer useful or correct than please consider +1 and check as correct.. do support someone's efforts... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you already initialized facebook object. Let say it is `$facebook`. If you want to logout  from your system with fb also, you can use following;

When user clicks logout link, redirect it to **logout.php** that has following code:

```
<?php

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'APP_SECRET'
));

...
// You can state a page that you want to redirect after logout also
$params = array( 'next' => 'https://your_site.com/callback_logout' );
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
header("Location:$logoutUrl");

?>
```